# What is the space of pseudo-Riemannian metrics?

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I want to know the structure of the space of pseudo-Riemannian metrics of definite signature (in particular I want $diag(-1,1,1,1)$). Is it possible to identify it with $R^{n(n+1)/2}$ which is the case for positive definite metrics? Any references are appreciated.

Comment: How do we identity the space of positive definite metrics with $\mathbb R^{n(n+1)/2}$?

Comment: Also, on which space do you intend to do so?

Comment: I intend to do it on $R^{n}$. For positive definite metrics my idea is that one can use Cholesky decomposition $g = LL^{T}$, where $L$ denotes lower triangular matrices with positive diagonal values. Such decomposition is unique. Now we have $n(n+1)/2$ entries characterizing our metric where the off-diagonal ones vary in $(-\inf,+ \inf)$ and diagonal ones vary in $(0,+\inf)$ which is however isomorphic to $(-\inf,+ \inf)$. The concrete isomorphism can be obtained taking $R^{n(n+1)/2}$ be the entries of $A$ - a lower triangular matrix with no restrictions on it's entries - and taking $L = e^A$